# How can I get preg_match_all to match angle brackets?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I know it's probably a dumb question, but I am stuck trying to figure out how to make preg_match_all to do what I want...

I want to match strings that look like <[someText]> 
Also, I would like to do this in a lazy fashion, so if a have a string like

```
$myString = '<[someText]> blah blah blah <[someOtherText]> lala [doNotMatchThis] ';
```

I would like to have 2 matches: '<[someText]>' and '<[someOtherText]>' as opposed to a single match '<[someText]> blah blah blah <[someOtherText]>'

I am trying to match this with the following pattern

```
$pattern = '<\[.+?\]>';
```

but for some reason, I'm getting 3 matches: [someText], [someOtherText] and [doNotMatchThis]

This leads me to believe that for some reason the angle brackets are interfering, which I find strange because they are not supposed to be metacharacters.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing correct delimiters (your `< >` are considered as delimiters in this case)

```
$pattern = '~<\[.+?\]>~';
```

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern needs delimiters (now the `<` and `>` are "seen" as delimiters).

Try this:

```
$pattern = '/<\[.+?\]>/';
```

The following:

```
$myString = '<[someText]> blah blah blah <[someOtherText]> lala [doNotMatchThis] ';
$pattern = '/<\[.+?\]>/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $myString, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

will print:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <[someText]>
            [1] => <[someOtherText]>
        )

)
```